# Diff giving inconsistent output

Tags: unix

I have 2 files as below temp1.csv

> 1111,abc,def
>
> 1111,ghi,jkl
>
> 4444,mno,pqr
>
> 5555,stu,vfx

And temp2.csv

> 1111,abc,def
>
> 1111,ghi,jkl
>
> 3333,abc,pqr
>
> 4444,mno,pqr
>
> 5555,stu,vfx

When I run diff -y temp1.csv temp2.csv

The output is

> 1111,abc,def                1111,abc,def
>
> 1111,ghi,jkl                   1111,ghi,jkl
>
> ```
>           >3333,abc,pqr
> ```
>
> 4444,mno,pqr                 4444,mno,pqr
>
> 5555,stu,vfx                   5555,stu,vfx

But when I edit the file temp2.csv and change mno to mnox on the 4th row

The diff commands mismatches the entries and gives a wrong output

The expected output is

> 1111,abc,def                1111,abc,def
>
> 1111,ghi,jkl              1111,ghi,jkl
>
> ```
>        >3333,abc,pqr
> ```
>
> 4444,mno,pqr                 ¦4444,mnox,pqr
>
> 5555,stu,vfx                    5555,stu,vfx

can someone please provide me a solution to this

Comment: Are you expecting column by column diff or line by line?

Comment: I think both
Line by line if it is a new entry
And column by column check to see if any columns are different 

See expected output

Comment: diff compares lines. Either the line is the same or it's not. It makes no attempt to find the closest approximate match among non-identical lines. You should look into the `join` utility - it seems more likely to be capable of doing what you want.